# Extract data from json format and paste to column_python

Tags: python, json, pandas

In my column with json data, I have this list I want to extract to column:

```
"list":[

{
    "id":"list",
    "item":[
        {
            "value":"Hergestellt in Italien aus 100% reinem Platin-Flüssigsilikon"
        },
        {
            "value":"Geruchs- und geschmacksneutral"
        },
        {
            "value":"Kältebeständig bis -60°C"
        },
        {
            "value":"Inklusive Rezeptbuch und 50 Eisstielen"
        },
        {
            "value":"spülmaschinengeeignet"
        }
    ],
    "decorators":[
    ]
},
```

I have extracted other data using this code but the value was string and not a dictionary:

```
dict_model_info = {}
df_cur_models = pd.DataFrame()
for i, model in enumerate(models):
    print("module-", i, ":")

    model_number = 'module-' + str(i + 1)

    cur_model_info = {}

    for k, v in model.items():
        if k == 'id' and isinstance(v, str):
            cur_model_info['module_id'] = v

        if 'item' in item and item['item']:
                    if isinstance(item['item'], str):
                        cur_model_info[item['id']] = item['item']
                    elif isinstance(item['item'], list):
                        cur_model_info[item['id']] = ','.join(item['item'])
```

I tried to use this for the above format of data but I got this error:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

What should I change in order to be able to export in a separate column the data having each element from the list in a new cell of that column?

The output should be in this format:

```
list
```

---

```
Hergestellt in Italien aus 100% reinem Platin-Flüssigsilikon
```

---

```
Geruchs- und geschmacksneutral
```

---

```
Kältebeständig bis -60°C
```

---

```
Inklusive Rezeptbuch und 50 Eisstielen
```

---

```
spülmaschinengeeignet
```

---

Comment: what is `item` variable and what is `cur_model_info`?

Comment: @Epsi95 I use cur_model_info which is a dictionary, to append data to a df. I will add the first part of the code in the description.

Comment: Still, after editing the question, you didn't specified what `item` is. This will break most likely.

Comment: @AdamTokarski it worked actually, the item is creating a column with the name found between 'id' and 'value'. Your code worked but I need to have the information after 'value' in separate cells

Comment: Please show how this should look like for given example.

Comment: @AdamTokarski thank you for your patience, I have updated the description

Comment: No problem. If you want to have this separated in new lines, just change `,` to `\n`, like `'\n'.join(elements)`.

Comment: @AdamTokarski thank you, my bad for not being more explicit, the need is for each information after 'value', to be pasted in a new cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228013/discussion-between-adam-tokarski-and-isa).

Comment: @AdamTokarski sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```py
elif isinstance(item['item'], list):
    elements = [element['value'] for element in item['item']]
    cur_model_info[item['id']] = '\n'.join(elements)
```

(updated to reflect output format added into description)

Comment: thank you so much but is there a way to export them separate in cells and not in the same cell separated by the comma?

Comment: What do you mean by `export them separate in cells`? You could pass them as a list still, ie. do `cur_model_info[item['id']] = elements`.